# Group of invertible elements make a multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Working with a nontrivial ring with unity, the set S of all the invertible elements in a ring is a multiplicative group.

So this is saying the invertible elements(or units) make a group that is closed under multiplication. So should I assume to have some invertible elements from my ring and show they are equal to 1? Then multiply the elements together to show the group is closed?

Let $a,b \in R$, where $R$ is a nontrival ring. $a$ and $b$ are invertible, thus for some $c$, $a\cdot c = c\cdot a =1$ and $b\cdot c =c\cdot b =1$. So $(a\cdot c) \cdot (b\cdot c) = 1\cdot 1 = 1$ thus $R$ is closed?

Comment: The inverse for $a.b$ is $b^{-1}.a^{-1}$, and $b^{-1}$ and $a^{-1}$ both need not be the same $c$.

Comment: Note that the additive structure is irrelevant here; this is true for any monoid.

Answer (score 1):

The ring is closed under multiplication.

The set of units is the set of ALL elements with multiplicative inverses.

The product of any two units has an inverse.  i.e. $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$

Since the set of units is contains all elements with inverseses $ab$ and $(ab)^{-1}$ must be in the set of units.